# SVN Update: what is the most efficient way of using it?

Tags: svn

There is an active SVN project in the remote server where there are two or more contributors (I'm the one).

The files that I have already have svn folders, so I do a:

```
svn diff
```

in my local copy to check for the changes..There is  now a difference between the file in the server and in my copy.

So If I do an:

```
svn update
```

Will it update the remote copy and overwrite the changes there? Or is it the opposite, it will download what is being changed there and merged with my copy?

After several hours, supposing I made the required changes, what is suggested?

1. Doing `svn diff` first before `svn update`?
2. Doing `svn update` before doing `svn commit`?

I want to make sure that I'm not overwriting some changes in the server made by other contributors.

Comment: Read the SVN book. It's a good read, and it's free. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running 'svn update' will not commit any of your changes to the server, so it's safe to do before you commit - although as you suspected, it will retrieve any changes made by others and merge them into your working copy.

If you want to preview what remote changes will be made to your working copy before running 'svn update', try:

```
svn status --show-updates
```

Running svn update just before commit (and before you start working!) is definitely recommended.

Comment: Thanks, it clears my mind. Is this similar to how svn diff works?

Comment: svn diff (when run without any special options) will display any differences between your working copy and the repository. You can use it to inspect the changes you've made before you commit them.

Answer (score 0):

`update` brings remote changes into your local copy, so you have nothing to fear by using it really at any time.

That said, if the remote changes are complex, then you risk losing the sanctity of your *local* changes into a mess of any conflicts caused.

I tend to do a `svn diff` fairly often to keep an eye on how my local working directory differs from the working base; when ready to go, I will then do an `svn update` to get everything up-to-date, do a final `svn diff` to get another view on what it is that I am doing, and finally perform the `svn commit`.

The only change to all this is that I use TortoiseSVN on Windows so the entire procedure is graphical and intuitive.